# Accessing a header or footer creates it, but leaving an empty one doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

My application uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word version 12 with embedded interop types to access Word 2007 and higher from a .NET 4.0 WPF application. It basically scans through a given Word document, replaces some things and then saves the document again.

Since I might have to replace things in the header/footer I have to access them. My problem is that accessing a header or footer in any way seems to create it (a paragraph mark gets shown) but leaving a empty header or footer doesn't remove that header/footer again like the Word UI does. This isn't a problem in a document with the default page margins but if the page has small margins a header can move the content of the page down, even if the header just contains an empty paragraph.

My question is: How can I either check the need to process a header/footer without causing Word to create one or how can I remove an empty header/footer by code?

This is basically the code I'm using:

```
Application application = new Application();
// Just for debugging.
application.Visible = true;
Document document = application.Documents.Open(filename);

foreach (Section section in document.Sections)
{
    HeaderFooter header = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];

    if (header == null || !header.Exists || header.LinkToPrevious)
    {
        // Header is disabled or linked to previous section.
        continue;
    }

    // We need to swith the view, otherwise some operations in the header
    // might fail.
    // This code is from a recorded Word macro.
    Window activeWindow = application.ActiveWindow;
    if (activeWindow.View.SplitSpecial != WdSpecialPane.wdPaneNone &&
        activeWindow.Panes.Count > 1)
    {
        activeWindow.Panes[2].Close();
    }
    activeWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView;
    activeWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekPrimaryHeader;

    // Get the full range of the header. This call causes my problem.
    Range headerRange = header.Range;

    // I'm doing something with 'headerRange' here, but this doesn't affect
    // the problem.

    // This switches the current view out of the header. Usually this also
    // deletes the header if it is empty. But if I accessed 'header.Range'
    // it doesn't delete it. Why?
    activeWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument;
}

application.Quit(SaveChanges: WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

Comment: Is the issue simply that the "HeaderFooter header = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdheaderPrimary];" has created the header. Wouldn't it be simpler to iterate the headerfooter collection?

Comment: @Jason Iterating over `section.Headers` or `section.Footers` always returns all three possible headers/footers. Accessing them by their `WdHeaderFooterIndex` doesn't create them (at least not in the visible Word UI), I've commented the code above that creates them (accessing `header.Range` or switching the `SeekView`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** I was able to reproduce the error with the info from your edit. To be honest, I am not sure why range does that, but if you're looking for a simple work around, this worked for me :

```
activeWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView;
activeWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekPrimaryHeader;

//Check for blank headers
activeWindow.ActivePane.Selection.WholeStory();
var text = activeWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Text;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text.Equals("\r"))
{
    activeWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument;
    continue;
}
// Get the full range of the header. This call causes my problem.
Range headerRange = header.Range;
```

Comment: Sorry for the missleading example code. I've now fixed it to show that the actual problem is accessing `header.Range`. If I never access the `Range` property, switching out of the header `SeekView` correctly removes the header. But once I accessed the `Range` property, this doesn't happen any more. I've tried to replace the text of the whole header range with an empty string but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: That range behaviour is really strange. I wish I could figure out why it does that, but for the time being I have added a work around so that empty headers are skipped. Hope this helps :)

Comment: So working with a `Range` causes the problem but working with a `Selection` doesn't. Another point for my "why I hate Office interop" list. Thanks for your help!